# Best way to move notification function from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, appdelegate, unusernotificationcenter

I have a function in the AppDelegate to handle rich notification, below is the test example of that. This function is called in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
func addNotification(){
   let acceptAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ACCEPT_ACTION",
         title: "Accept",
         options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))
   let declineAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "DECLINE_ACTION",
         title: "Decline",
         options: UNNotificationActionOptions(rawValue: 0))

   let meetingInviteCategory =
         UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "MEETING",
         actions: [acceptAction, declineAction],
         intentIdentifiers: [],
         hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: "",
         options: .customDismissAction)

   let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([meetingInviteCategory])
}
```

This is a test function, in the actual use, it will get much bigger, I want to move it in the another file. Something like that:

```
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

public class AppNotifications {

   func addNotification(){
...
```

Then I can call it in the AppDelagate, now I have a question; is it fine that I create a class that just contains some functions? Or there is a better way that you can recommend me?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If your class is just a container for some functions and you don't need instances of that class, then you can use static functions. Defined with `static func addNotifiaction()` and called with `AppNotifications.addNotification()`

Comment: You mean I create a class and inside of it, I add static func?

Comment: Exactly, just like you did in you example. You only need to add the static keyword to those functions in the class.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help

Comment: If the problem is trivially solved, please delete the question.